# How to receive feedback from classRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I needed to implement with a custom-renderer a map in my project developed with Xamarin Forms, here is how I did it:

```
public class MyMap : Map
    {
        public MyMap ():base(){ }
    }
```

MapView(Xamarin Forms):

```
public class MapView:ContentPage
    {
            List<Filiale> list=jM.ReadData ();
            MyMap myMap = new MyMap (//I'd like to pass list here);
            var stack = new StackLayout ();
            myMap.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            myMap.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
            stack.Children.Add (myMap);
            Content = stack;
}
```

MapRenderer (Xamarin iOS):

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MyMap), typeof (MapiOS))]
namespace App.iOS
{
    public class MapiOS : MapRenderer
    {
    private MKMapView NativeMap { get { return (this.NativeView as MapRenderer).Control as MKMapView; } }
    public MapiOS ():base()
    {

    }

    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);
        MyMapDelegate myMapDelegate = new MyMapDelegate ();
        NativeMap.Delegate = myMapDelegate;
        NativeMap.AddAnnotation(new MKPointAnnotation (){
            Title=list[0].nome,
            Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (42.364260, -71.120824)
        });
    }
}
```

In the `myMapDelegate` class I also handled the click on a button displayed from clicking on the Pins like this:

```
public override void CalloutAccessoryControlTapped (MKMapView mapView, MKAnnotationView view, UIControl control){
            //Call new Page
        }
```

Now when this button is clicked I'd like to get back to Xamarin Forms and create a new page with it. How should I do it? Also How can I pass some object when I create the MyMap object?

Comment: Just to understand. The list you'd like to pass to `MyMap`: Is that a list of locations?
And when you click a pin, some method should be called on your `MapView`

Comment: the list is the list declared in the example of type Filiale.
And the method called is on MyMapDelegate, the CalloutAccessoryTapped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `MyMap` implementation to this

```cs
public class MyMap : Map
{
  public static readonly BindableProperty LocationsProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MyMap, List<string>>(x => x.Locations, new List<string>());
  public static readonly BindableProperty PinTappedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MyMap, Command>(x=>x.PinTapped, null);

  public MyMap(List<string> locations)
  {
    Locations = locations;
    PinTapped = new Command(async (x) =>
    {
      await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
      await Navigation.PushAsync(SomeNewPage(x));
    });
  }

  public List<string> Locations
  {
    get { return (List<string>)GetValue(LocationsProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LocationsProperty, value); }
  }

  public Command PinTapped 
  {
    get { return (Command) GetValue(PinTappedCommandProperty); }
    set { SetValue(PinTappedCommandProperty, value);}
  }
}
```

Now you can access `Locations` from your MapRenderer by changing it slightly:

```
public class MapiOS : ViewRenderer<MyMap, MKMapView>
{
  protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<MyMap> e)
  {
    base.OnElementChanged (e);

    var map = e.NewElement; // Remember to check for null
    var locations = map.Locations;
    // Do what you want with locations

    var cmd = Map.PinTapped; // Send this along to MyMapDelegate
    var nativeMap = new MKMapView(); // Initiate with relevant parameters
    SetNativeControl(nativeMap)

    MyMapDelegate myMapDelegate = new MyMapDelegate (cmd); // Change constructor here
    nativeMap.Delegate = myMapDelegate;
    nativeMap.AddAnnotation(new MKPointAnnotation (){
        Title=list[0].nome,
        Coordinate = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (42.364260, -71.120824)
    });

  }
```

I have assumed that you have shown the map as a modal inside a NavigationPage or similar.

You now have the Command, so bring it along to your `MyMapDelegate` and use

```
x.PinTapped.Execute("YourParameter");
```

Comment: You should be able to accomplish the rest by adding a `Command` to MyMap that you invoke when clicking your button

Comment: @DQuaglio I have updated the answer. I hope it helps

Comment: @DQuaglio I've added the code to show how to access Locations and PinTapped from iOS

Comment: @Dquaglio Answer updated. Hope it helps. I don't have a Mac available at the moment, so I'm guessing a little

Comment: now it may work, but it doesn't even enter in MapiOS when executing the app, and the map is not shown, something is wrong in MyMap..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68993/discussion-between-angak-and-dquaglio).

Comment: Maybe you can help me with this if you want [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172624/xamarin-forms-android-maprenderer)