# Xamarin Forms Android MapRenderer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I created successfully a ViewRenderer for Xamarin iOS and now I'm trying to implement a Renderer for Android, here is the Map That I need to implement in Android:

```
public class MapViewModel : Map
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty LocationsProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MapViewModel, List<Branch>>(x => x.Locations, new List<Branch>());
        public static readonly BindableProperty PinTappedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MapViewModel, Command>(x => x.PinTapped, null);

        public MapViewModel(List<Branch> locations)
        {
            Locations = locations;
            PinTapped = new Command(async (x) =>
                {
                    //await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
                    var info = new InformationView((Branch)x);
                    await Navigation.PushAsync(info);
                });
        }

        public List<Branch> Locations
        {
            get { return (List<Branch>)GetValue(LocationsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(LocationsProperty, value); }
        }

        public Command PinTapped 
        {
            get {return (Command) GetValue(PinTappedCommandProperty); }
            set {SetValue(PinTappedCommandProperty, value);}
        }
    }
```

Following what I did for iOS I did this for Android:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof (MapViewModel), typeof (MapViewAndroid))]
public class MapViewAndroid : ViewRenderer<MapViewModel, global::Android.Gms.Maps.MapView>
    {
        private global::Android.Gms.Maps.MapView NativeMap {get { return Control; } }

        public MapViewAndroid ()
        {
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<MapViewModel> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var map = e.NewElement;
            var cmd = map.PinTapped;
            SetNativeControl(NativeMap);
        }
}
```

The Control is null, so I can't `SetNativeControl` properly and in Application Output I read : `[art] JNI RegisterNativeMethods: attempt to register 0 native methods for kimo.customersapp.android.MapViewAndroid`...
What I'm missing for this to works?

Comment: Compared to your iOS implementation, there seem's to be missing a call to SetNativeControl. Maybe you could look into that

Comment: The problem is that my Control is null, so I can't retrieve the MapView and set the NativeControl with it... I must be missing something else.

Answer (score 2):

Google maps can take some time to initialize. You need to wait for it to fully load before you can use it. Also make sure you hook into IOnMapReadyCallback so that you get notified when the map is ready to use.

```
private GoogleMap NativeMap { get;set;}
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged (sender, e);
    if (e.PropertyName.Equals ("VisibleRegion")) {
        var targetElement = (Android.Gms.Maps.MapView)Control;
        if (NativeMap == null) {
            targetElement.GetMapAsync (this);
        }
    }

}
```